# Regular expression Decimals (Dynamic) Java

Tags: java, regex, decimal

I need your help because I have a regular expression to validate what type of floating point is receiving, this is because the decimal separator can arrive as `.` or`,`I do not have the way to force a single type of separator so so much I want to validate it by a `regex` and I have not been able to finish it, I have tried in several ways and I do not manage to obtain the expected result, you can guide me please.

**Numbers:**
`171`,`171.00`, `1770`,`1,700`, `1,700.00`,`1,777,777`, `1,777,777.00`,,`1777777.00`

**Regular phrase**

1. Option: `String patternString = "^[0-9]{0,3}+|(\\,[0-9]{0,3})+(\\.[0-9]{0,2})?$`
2. Option: `String patternString = "^[0-9]{0,3}|(\\,[0-9]{0,3})(\\.[0-9]{0,2})?$";`
3. Option: `String patternString = "^[0-9]+(\\,[0-9]{0,})+(\\.[0-9]{0,})?$ | ^[0-9]+(\\,[0-9]{0,})?$";`
4. Option: `String patternString = "^[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]{0,})+(\\,[0-9]{0,})?$";`

---

**Expected result:**

For this case I am only evaluating where the pattern of the number is `#, ## 0.00`, for the other case I would believe that it would only be to invest the`,`for the`.`

**Option 1:**

- `1.71` - Ok
- `1.71717171` - Ok
- `171` - Ok
- `171.00` - Ok
- `1770` - Ok
- `1,700` - Ok
- `1,700.00` - Ok
- `1,777,777` - Ok
- `1,777,777.00` - Ok
- `1777777.00` - Ok

**Option 2:**

- `171,00` - Error (False)
- `1,700.00` - Error (False)
- `1,777,777` - Error (False)
- `1,777,777.00` - Error (False)
- `1777777,00` - Error (False)
- `1,00` - Error (False)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example numbers, you start with 1+ times a digit. What follows is an optional repeated part that matches a comma and 3 times a digit and the numbers end with an optional dot and 2 times a digit or a dot followed by 1+ times a digit.

You might use and [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html):

```
^\d+(?:(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d{1,2})?|\.\d+)$
```

In Java:

```
String regex = "^\\d+(?:(?:,\\d{3})*(?:\\.\\d{1,2})?|\\.\\d+)$";
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of the string
- `\d+` Match 1+ digits
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `(?:,\d{3})*` Repeat 0+ times matching comma and 3 digits
  - `(?:\.\d{1,2})?` Optionally match a dot and 2 digits
- `|` Or
- `\.\d+` Match dot and 1+ digits
- `)` Close non capturing group
- `$` End of the string

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/c2u0tH/1)

Comment: this great thousand thanks, and that website is wonderful, I did not know it. :)